# How to catch the exception when a dll is not found?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a Windows Forms App. Here is a plain structure of the app:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    dllLibrary dll_object = new dllLibrary();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        dll_object.Init();
        dll_object.method1(); 
        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dll_object.method2();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dll_object.method3();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        dll_object.Finalize();
    }
}
```

It is just an example of how I create the object of the library and use the methods of the library by using this object when I click a button. To use the same object for different methods of a class I create it outside of any method.

Before I put the dll in a folder on my PC, registered it by Command Prompt and added the reference to it in Solution Explorer.

However, if the dll is deleted from the folder, for example, the exception arises. I want users to see the message that the dll has not been found. How can I do it if I can? I can't put the 'dllLibrary object = new dllLibrary();' line inside the try statement to catch the exception and then show a message box. I can't put this line inside any method of the class because I have to run the library's methods for the same object.

I've read a lot of articles but in this articles, dlls are just called inside a method.

Comment: First of all: `object` is a keyword and I would suggest not to use it as variable name. But outside this: you only need to have the declaration on class level. You very well can instantiate the dependency in your constructor _or even better:_ inject it via dependency injection.

Comment: `if the dll is deleted from the folder` is this a actual use-case or is this a [layer eight problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_8)? ;)

Comment: The next method `public Form1()` is the one you should put the try-catch block in.

Comment: Don't let people delete DLLs. You can't catch this inside `Form1`, not even the constructor. In `new dllLibrary();` you're creating a class, not loading a DLL. Fields are initialized *before* the constructor is called, so your code will throw a TypeLoadException or something similar long before calling the constructor.

Comment: What you describe is the very reason `Program Files` is a read-only folder. To prevent users or badly written programs, including bad installers, from breaking other applications. In recent Windows versions you can't modify those folders even if you try to force the permissions - Windows will redirect changes to a different folder.

Comment: That's why you should use proper installers instead of just copying files too. A proper installer registers an application's files so even if the files are deleted, Windows itself will revert them when the user runs the application.

Comment: What's the *real* question behind this? What happened?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your comments. I use some libraries added to the project by NuGet Package Manager. When I release the app, these libraries are included in the release folder with the exe file. For my project I also use the dll library to work with digital signatures and sertificates. The library was developed by the government of Kazakhstan. Its developers provide the instruction of how to install it. You have to put it in a folder on your PC and then register it by regsvr32 in cmd.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We're going to put my app on a server so our users with the access to this server can run the app on their local PCs. I've already tried to put the dll on the server and registered it. But this way doesn't guarantee that the library will be registered. Sometimes it wasn't registered sysadmins said to me. So I decided to find a way to catch the exception when the dll doesn't exist.

Comment: `The library was developed by the government of Kazakhstan.` sorry, helping people hack others is explicitly against SO rules. Yes, I know what you mean, and how you can register that malware.

Comment: That malware is a COM dll, like other, useful libraries and components. Installers can deploy and register COM dlls just fine, although Windows may display the UAC dialog asking for permission. That's a built-in Windows security mechanism available since the 2000s to prevent applications from making significant changes behind a user's back

Comment: As for why the malware fails to register, it's precisely because Windows prevents it from installing without either Administrator privileges or, in the case of normal COM dlls, UAC acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you'd like to notify the user that a dynamic link library (DLL) cannot be found if it does not exist.

Personally, I would make a separate launcher for the program. It does not import any library.

The launcher would first check if all files (DLLs) are present, and if at least one dynamic link library is deleted or renamed, give an error and do not launch the program, otherwise the EXE should launch.

Haven't tested this yet, but here's an example.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProgramLauncher
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Using console here. It can be Windows Forms as well.
            
            string EXEPathToLaunch = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%PROGRAMFILES%\\MyEXE\\ProgramThatShouldLaunch.exe");
            
            if (!File.Exists("DLL.dll") || !File.Exists("DLL2.dll"))
            {
                // These are 2 dynamic link libraries that would be imported to the program that you would like to launch.
                // You can replace those DLL filenames with anything else.
                // You can check as more DLLs as your program uses.
                
                // Here we would notify the user that one or two of specified dynamic link libraries do not exist.
                
                Console.WriteLine("DLL does not exist! Cannot launch!"); // You can replace this with a Message Box if the launcher is also Windows Forms.
                Environment.Exit(1); // The Console Application will close.
            } else {
                // Run the program if all DLLs are present and not deleted or renamed
                // We can also check if the EXE exists or not.
                if (!File.Exists(EXEPathToLaunch))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("EXE does not exist! Cannot launch!"); // You can also replace this with a Message Box if the launcher is also Windows Forms.
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                } else {
                    Process.Start(EXEPathToLaunch); // Starts the needed EXE if the EXE itself and other DLLs are found. That way, there's no need to worry if a DLL does not exist.
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, "object" is a keyword that is similar to var. I do not recommend using it as variable names.

Edit: You can load the DLL at runtime, instead of adding a DLL reference. If I remember correctly, adding a DLL reference is also loading the DLL at compile time, instead of runtime. So if the DLL is not found, the program cannot proceed, but if we're loading the DLL at runtime, and it's corrupt or not found, we can handle the exception gracefully and continue the execution of the application, give an error, disable some feature, or something else. However, I do have to warn that the performance of the program may drop. If you really care about performance, I recommend adding a DLL reference instead of loading at runtime. There's [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GjDl9y9t0g) that shows how to load DLL at runtime and invoke a method.

If you're importing a C# dynamic link library, here's how. I have to warn that I haven't tested the code, so mistakes may happen.

source of AppComponent.dll:

```cs
namespace AppComponent
{
    public class Components
    {
        public static string Greet(string user)
            => $"Hello, {user}!";
    }
}
```

code to load AppComponent.dll, and call Greet:

```
...
string appcomponent = @".\AppComponent.dll"; // assuming the dll is in the same folder
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(appcomponent);
var type = assembly.GetType("AppComponent.Components"); // namespace.class
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var method = type.GetMethod("Greet"); // method, in this case - AppComponent.Components.Greet
var result = method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "someone" }); // invoke method, pass an array of System.Object, which describes methods parameters
Console.WriteLine(result); // Hello, someone!
```

If you wish [to load C/C++ DLL at runtime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-ass4mkdiA), use [DllImportAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-7.0).

source of cppdll.dll:

```cpp
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int AddFive(int input) {
        return input + 5;
    }
}
```

C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

[DllImport("cppdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl /* important, because of __declspec(dllexport), which tells the C++ compiler that any program can use that method*/)]
public static extern int AddFive(int input);

...
Console.WriteLine(AddFive(2)); // 7
```

If the DLL is missing, inaccessiable, or corrupt, you will also get a throw statement whenever you try to call the method, since it is loaded at runtime, which can be added to the try/catch block.

But again, loading a C# DLL at runtime is slower and much more complex than adding a DLL reference. Most developers prefer to add a DLL reference, since, well, everyone wants their program to run perfect, so to guarantee no breakage, the program has to exit if there's an issue - especially with a DLL.

Oh, and in Windows Forms, where should you add the part to load DLL at runtime? I recommend in the entry point. It can be found at the file `Program.cs`, and should look similar to:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Moreover, you don't have to worry much when the DLL is deleted. Everyone has tried to delete a random DLL even from their installation directory, like in Program Files folder, and it yields the application in an unintended state. Therefore, it's generally alright if your program can't start if the DLL isn't found. This is exactly the same for every other program.
People are not stupid to delete DLLs by accident maybe. Whenever the user installs the software, there's obviously no point to delete its core files - everyone knows something will happen with the program. In general, there's not really need to work with things like installers that recover files whenever the program is ran.
Think of your program as a laptop that's stuck at 0% battery and won't charge, and the DLL file is the charger. If the DLL file isn't found or fails, the laptop will power off. Makes sense - it needs battery to operate. So we have something similar going on with programs. If the program can't find a DLL, well, there's no need to continue.
With that being said, don't worry about missing DLLs. But if you really care about that anyway, loading the DLL at runtime is probably going to help.

I hope this helps

Comment: You're describing what Windows installers and the OS already do. Installers will actually *repair* the missing DLLs, not just detect them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not describing an installer, or it's just me misunderstanding it? I was explaining to make another program that would simply check if all required DLLs (or other files vital to the program functionality) are not deleted or renamed or moved, and if they aren't, launch the program. Otherwise, give an error. If an edit to the answer is required, please let me know.

Comment: That's what installers do. There's no need to add an extra program to do what the OS can already do far better